# Why does loading an NSArray from pList turn my array into an NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, exception, ios5, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here's my problem: I load a plist into an NSArray.  I'm not declaring any NSDictionary anywhere in my app.

Now I have a UIPickerView.  I want it to be populated from said NSArray that sits as private member of my view controller.  My picker requires the "titleForRow" method to be implemented.  If I implement it like this it crashes:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [airportList objectAtIndex:row];    
}
```

However if I implement it like this it works:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
NSDictionary *stupid = (NSDictionary *)airportList;
NSString *airPortName = [stupid objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item%d",row]];
NSLog(@"%@",airPortName);
return airPortName;   
}
```

Why is my NSArray automatically converted to an NSDictionary?

Edit *:
Here's how I generate my NSArray from the plist:

```
-(NSArray *)createAirportList
{
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AirportList" ofType:@"plist"];
   NSData *plistAirportNames = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
   NSString *error;
   NSPropertyListFormat format;    
   NSArray *airportNames = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistAirportNames mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error]; 
   if(!airportNames)
   {
       NSLog(@"Could not read the airport name. Error:%@",error);
   }
   return airportNames;   
}
```

My plist is just key: Item0 string "blah". So yeah its kinda like a dictionary but why can't I use an NSArray object that I've created?  What's with the auto-typecasting?

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your airportList?

Comment: How do you store the plist and how do you load it?

Comment: I added my plist loading method above in an edit.  @Zaph I'm declaring an NSArray, not an NSDictionary.  I understand that an NSDictionary could be also an NSArray, but I don't understand why, if thats the case, I can't access the contents of my NSArray using objectAtIndex.

Comment: Provide some of the beginning of the `plist`, perhaps as displayed in a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write:

> My plist is just key: Item0 string "blah"

That is a dictionary. `NSDictionary` and dictionaries in general do not have an order, they are accessed by key value.

An `NSArray` can not be an `NSDictionary` and visa-versa, they are distinct types. It is not your "plist loading method" but the `plist` it self, the way the `plist` was created.

The top element of the `plist` can be either an array or a dictionary and that determines wether it is an `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray` when it is loaded.

Looking at the plist in Xcode or a text editor will help you understand what is happening. Use `NSLog()` to view the loaded plist, that will also provide insight into the actual structure of the `plist`.

What you may find is that there is a top level dictionary that has the array you are looking for as a dictionary item. Or that the data you want is indeed a dictionary and you will need to use `NSDictionary=` methods to access the item you need.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
NSArray *airportNames = [NSPropertyListSerialization 
                            propertyListFromData:plistAirportNames 
                            mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                            format:&format errorDescription:&error];
```

does not "load your plist into an array", it loads whatever object is in your plist and assigns a reference to that to a pointer of type `NSArray *`.

In Objective-C objects are untyped. Programmers use typed pointers for readability and so that the compiler can provide suitable warnings.

Nevertheless, the `id` type is available, which stands for an untyped object. Any type can be assigned to `id` and `id` objects can be assigned to any other type. In those cases the compiler can't check what you're doing statically so you need to use your own judgment.

In this case your plist clearly contains a dictionary. So `NSPropertyListSerialization` loads and returns a dictionary, as type `id` because it may return any property type. Simply storing it as an `NSArray *` does not affect its type in memory.

Probably you want to take the dictionary and call `allKeys` or `allValues` to get an array representing the elements in the dictionary one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Check your plist? Make sure it's not actually an NSDictionary there.